# How to watch an input textbox using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

This is my textbox

```
<input id="txtbox1" type="text"/>
```

Is their anyway in javascript to watch this textbox textchange without using events like `onchange`,`onblur` just like `$watch` in angularjs,

```
<input ng-model='modelname' type='text'/>
```

By using angularjs I can watch this by `$watch`,
I want same as this one but in pure Javascript.
Because I have a file that uses only Javascript functions so I just want to watch the textchange of value.

Comment: there is an event called `oninput`

Comment: Why do you not want to use an event listener Syed?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener  If your intention is to keep js code out of html... Also, you could use 'keyup', for example.

Comment: In fact, `$watch` is also based on events. you can't do it without events...

Comment: angular also use events

Comment: because i eventually want to  watch that input textbox and i have seperate javascript file from that i apply value to it using its`id` and i watch that in angualrjs code without using ngmodel for that textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('txtbox1').addEventListener('input',function(e){
 console.log('typing');
},false);
```

Text element have a 'input' event, it will be fired up when user typing in it.

Comment: Thanks i got it after some changes in your code :)
http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/eqemx218/